# Group by in table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

My code is :

```
SELECT
    Student_ID ,dbo.tblVahed.Vahed_ID,
    COUNT(Student_ID) AS State_All,
    CASE 
       WHEN tblStudentsDocument.Student_Sex = N'مرد'  
          THEN COUNT(Student_ID) 
    END AS Count_Man,
    CASE 
       WHEN tblStudentsDocument.Student_Sex = N'زن'  
          THEN COUNT(Student_ID) 
    END AS Count_Woman 
FROM         
    dbo.tblStudentsDocument 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.tblVahed ON dbo.tblStudentsDocument.Vahed_ID = dbo.tblVahed.Vahed_ID
GROUP BY 
    dbo.tblVahed.Vahed_ID, Student_ID, Student_Sex
```

but I should `group by` only `dbo.tblVahed.Vahed_ID`. Any help appreicated.

Answer (score 0):

Anything that's not aggregated in the SELECT field list must be included in the group by. If you don't want to group by it, then you shouldn't include it in the select list unaggregated. Your query should work as follows.

```
SELECT dbo.tblVahed.Vahed_ID, 
    COUNT( Student_ID) AS State_All , 
    SUM(CASE WHEN tblStudentsDocument.Student_Sex = N'مرد' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Count_Man ,
    SUM(CASE WHEN tblStudentsDocument.Student_Sex = N'زن' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Count_Woman
FROM dbo.tblStudentsDocument 
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblVahed ON dbo.tblStudentsDocument.Vahed_ID = dbo.tblVahed.Vahed_ID
GROUP BY dbo.tblVahed.Vahed_ID
```

Note I've removed student id, and rewritten the case statement to perform the aggregation in a different way.

Comment: tank you but i needed sum  group by Vahed_ID

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to edit the group by clause to remove the two fields that shouldn't be grouped. Is it better now?